# Optimize images for the mobile website

Tags: image, image-processing, jpeg, image-compression

I was trying to figure out the issues with the existing page using  PageSpeed Insights. So, I came across the following results which says optimize your images but i am already using the JPG format with 90% quality settings. Moreover, same url doesn't give any issues with the Desktop tab of the PageSpeed Insights. So, what could be the problem where can i optimize further keeping the same JPG format.

```
Optimize images
    Properly formatting and compressing images can save many bytes of data.
    Optimize the following images to reduce their size by 118.5KiB (49% reduction).
    Losslessly compressing URL1 could save 44KiB (52% reduction).
    Losslessly compressing URL2 could save 27.5KiB (56% reduction).
    Losslessly compressing URL3 could save 24.8KiB (44% reduction).
    Losslessly compressing URL4 could save 15.3KiB (63% reduction).
    Losslessly compressing URL5 could save 7KiB (22% reduction).
```

[image]

Comment: Where did you get the flowchart - seems odd it doesn't mention transparency as a deciding factor. You could also try stripping the EXIF/other meta data from your images, reducing the colours and reducing the quality.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/image-optimization